# Javascript Math.random() not *that* random…?

Tags: javascript, random

I wrote a litte function in Javascript that displays a random picture. The actual line returning the pics number looks like this:

```
num = Math.floor(Math.random() * RNDGALSIZE);
```

with RNDGALSIZE currently = 72.

however, i felt that some pictures are hit quite often while others didnt come for quite a time, so I wrote a loop to generate `num` some number of times, and record how many times each value of `num` appeared. Here is the result:

```
2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2,    // num = 0 to 9
2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1,    // num = 10 to 19
1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1,    // num = 20 to 29
1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0,    // num = 30 to 39
2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3,    // num = 40 to 49
2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1,    // num = 50 to 59
2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1,    // num = 60 to 69
3, 1                             // num = 70 and 71
```

As you can see, no value appeared more than 3 times, and sixteen values did not occur at all. While some values might not occur, i think 16 is way to much. Is there anything wrong with my aproach?

Update:

A little Later:

```
4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2,
4, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 4, 4,
2, 0, 5, 3, 0, 4, 2, 0, 2, 1,
2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 0, 5,
4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1,
2, 2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1,
4, 1,
```

As you can see, while the 3 is hit 6 times, there still 7 zeroes in the array :/

Comment: are you sure `RNDGALSIZE` is `72` and not `4`?

Comment: If it where 4, how would i get array[71] filled with 1??

Comment: Can you post the code that generated that list of numbers?

Comment: @go-oleg: imgnum[num]++;

Comment: @rhavin Are you sure about the value of `RNDGALSIZE`? If it really is 72, there's a real reason to worry about `Math.random()` randomness... ; ).

Comment: @Teemu: Well, it is 72… what's the point?

Comment: @The point is, that if  `RNDGALSIZE` would be 72, your randomized numbers should be between 0 and 71, now there are numbers between 0 and 3, and later 0 and 4.

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). If the problem is as fundamental as you make it to be, that should be rather easy.

Comment: @Teemu: You didnt read the question: Those are not the numbers generated, those are the times a number *is* generated. So the number 32 in the second example has been generated zero times!

Comment: *"...some here simply cant read"* No, you've done a terribly poor job of laying out your "question". (I'm not even certain there's an actual question here.)

Comment: @rhavin I'm sorry for misunderstood your "array", now I get it.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: "so i wrote a little array that captures the times a certain number is choosen" … how could that be not understood?

Comment: The layout of your question is quite poor, though slowly improving. I don't doubt that all the information is present. I'm saying the presentation of the information is lacking.

Comment: @rhavin: Well, it's not English, so it's likely not to be understood by English-speakers. ;-) If you'd like assistance with your English, there's actually [a separate StackExchange site for that](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @rhavin Don't these two tables rather proove, that `Math.random()` returns random values, they are clearly not shared even within the given limit or by any other predefined distribution pattern.

Comment: @ruakh: ?? Im no nativespeaker, but … whats wrong with the sentence?

Comment: @Teemu: They dont provide a gaussian distribution of the times a number is hit, that what i would expect in a random choosen number between 0 and 71: If Ø of hit is 3, 0 and 6 should happen likewise often.

Comment: @rhavin: Well, the most salient problems are: "i" for "I"; "wrote a little array that captures [...]" for "wrote some code that captures [...] in an array"; "the times" for "the number of times"; and "choosen" for "chosen". Most of these problems were not real barriers to understanding, but your use of "the times" to mean "the number of times" was a sincere problem. When you write in poor English, people have to make guesses as to what you mean -- and often they don't even realize that they're making guesses. (So much of communication is guessing, and we don't notice it till it goes wrong.)

Comment: @rhavin Gaussian distribution is a "law of nature", computers are not natural. Values returned by `Math.random()` are calculated and actually they do have a pattern. How they are calculated, depends on the implementation. Feel free to check how it's done, many browsers have an open code source.

Comment: You need a large enough sample to be able to be able to find out if there is something wrong with the random number generator. Try it with one million random numbers.

Comment: First of all, in your first set of results, you appear to be generating random numbers `91` times. In the second set, `194` times. Why the difference? Second, I can't reproduce results anywhere close to yours. I never get a `0`. Are you sure you're incrementing your counter correctly?

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Just because i wanted to get shure that the results wouldnt become more gaussian in reasonable time.

Comment: @rhavin If the native random number generator is not satisfying your needs, you can always implement your own generator around [Gaussian function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, solution would be to keep track of how often a number was hit and in case the random-generator hits a number, that has been hit already to often, provide a number that has been ignored to often…

```
var minhit = Number.MAX_VALUE;
var maxhit = 1;
var index_min = 0;
for (i=0; i<RNDGALSIZE; i++)
{
  if (imgnum[i] < minhit)
  {
    minhit = imgnum[i];
  index_min = i;
  }
  else if (imgnum[i]>maxhit)
  {
    maxhit = imgnum[i];
  }
}
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * RNDGALSIZE);
if (imgnum[num] == maxhit)
{
  num = index_min;
}
imgnum[num]++;
```

Result:

```
2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1,
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1,
```

Comment: A better approach would be to populate an array with all values 0..71 (maybe two or three times each, so you don't get total uniqueness), then shuffle that array with a simple [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), and just iterate over that array to determine the order to present pictures in.

Answer (score 3):

(This is to elaborate on lossleader's answer.)

Let `p[n][k]` denote the probability, after `n` trials, that exactly `k` distinct values (out of 72) will have appeared. It's hard to give an exact closed-form expression, but we can compute it pretty easily using dynamic programming:

```
var p = [];

p[0] = [];
p[0][0] = 1; // after 0 trials, 100% chance that 0 values have appeared
for(var k = 1; k <= 72; ++k) {
    p[0][k] = 0
}

for(var n = 1; n < 1000; ++n) {
    p[n] = [];
    p[n][0] = 0;
    for(var k = 1; k < n && k <= 72; ++k) {
        p[n][k] = p[n-1][k] * k / 72 + p[n-1][k-1] * (72-k+1) / 72;
    }
    if(n <= 72) {
        p[n][n] = p[n-1][n-1] * (72-n+1) / 72;
    }
    for(var k = n + 1; k <= 72; ++k) {
        p[n][k] = 0;
    }
}
```

Given this, we can compute the probability that after `n` trials, we will still have at least `z` "zeroes" (values that haven't appeared even once):

```
function probabilityAfterNTrialsOfAtLeastZZeroes(n, z) {
    var ret = 0;
    for(var k = 0; k <= 72 - z; ++k) {
        ret += p[n][k];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

So the probability that after 91 trials, we still have 16 or more "zeroes" is `probabilityAfterNTrialsOfAtLeastZZeroes(91, 16)`, i.e. 0.959, which is 96%. (It's actually slightly surprising that you had as *few* as you did: the probability of having 17 or more "zeroes" is 0.914, so the probability of having 16 or fewer is only 8.6%.)

Similarly, the probability that after 194 trials, we still have 7 or more "zeroes" is `probabilityAfterNTrialsOfAtLeastZZeroes(194, 7)`, i.e. 0.179, which is 18%. So you'd generally expect fewer than 7 "zeroes" after 194 trials, but if you repeat the experiment many times, you'd expect 7-or-more "zeroes" almost every one in five times.

We can also compute the expected number of "zeroes" after `n` trials:

```
function expectedZeroesAfterNTrials(n) {
    var ret = 0;
    for(var z = 0; z <= 72; ++z) {
        ret += z * p[n][72-z];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

After 91 trials, we expect `expectedZeroesAfterNTrials(91)` "zeroes", i.e. 20.164, and after 194 trials, we expect 4.775 "zeroes".

Answer (score 1):

Your numbers look pretty reasonable,

```
Math.pow((71/72),194)*72 // odds of missing a number ^ tries * number of slots
4.774719247726743
```

Since we can't get a fraction, it looks like you should have 5 instead of 7 "zeros" if we lived in a "deterministic random" world.

Instead you should just do a choose with no replace and then restart the pool at 0.

*edit* a quick and dirty 100 test count you can run from the jsconsole:

```
function do_test() { x = []; for (var i = 0 ; i < 72 ; i++) x.push(0); for (var j = 0; j < 194; j++) x[Math.floor(Math.random()*72)]++; count = 0; for (var i = 0 ; i < 72 ; i++) if (!x[i]) count++; return count;}


function do_tests(n) { y = []; for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) y.push(do_test()); return y;}

z = do_tests(100)
```

[5, 5, 3, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7, 4, 3, 7, 6, 5, 8, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 8, 3, 4, 7, 8, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 3, 6, 1, 3, 6, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 7, 4, 11, 6, 5, 9, 5, 3, 6, 7, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 2, 5, 9, 6]

```
j = 0; for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) j+=z[i];
```

473  // so 4.73 zero slots was the average of this 100 runs...

Comment: I upvoted this earlier -- and I'm happy with my upvote, because this gives the right general idea -- but I'd like to note that this is not actually an exact formula for the expected number of zeroes, because the probability that one value is missed is not independent of the probability that another value is missed.

Comment: I've been considering this, but I don't think it would have much affect unless there were very few slots.. Still, to be sure I actually ran a test 100 times and got 4.85 as the average number of 0's..

Comment: Of course, if the question is "Is this a good random number generator?", then it's cheating to use it to compute the expectations. :-P But yes, you're right that the non-independence has little effect. I just computed the expected value after taking it into account (see my "answer"), and got 4.774719247726673, which matches your value to 12 places past the decimal. I didn't expect it to be that close!

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming chrome's optimizer doesn't have enough insight to identify such an equivalence and/or wouldn't share an algorithm bug with my brain. :)